# monic polynomial as gcd and lcm

Tags: polynomials, ring-theory, gcd-and-lcm

I am wondering why the gcd/lcm of polynomials have to be monic. The idea that constant multiples of it cannot also be gcd/lcms makes sense to me but I am unsure what happens when we evaluate the gcd/lcm of say, $4x^2-1$ and $2x-1$ in the $\mathbb{Z}[x]$ ring.

The intuitive gcd would be $4x^2-1$ and lcm $2x-1$, but they are not monic so they cannot be gcd/lcms by the stricter definition.

Comment: I don't know exactly in what context everything is said, but I would _assume_ that it's only over $\Bbb Q$ and $\Bbb R$ they demand that the polynomials are monic, since otherwise there is no _uniqueness_. Over $\Bbb Z$, it's enough to say that the leading coefficient should be positive, and you have a unique lcm and gcd. Are you certain that they said that the polynomials had to be monic in the context of $\Bbb Z[x]$?

Comment: When the coefficients are from any field, the leading coefficient of the gcd can be made an arbitrary nonzero element from that field, so for consistency we insist that it's 1.  When the coefficients are not from a field, things are more complicated.

Comment: @Arthur I'm using the Rotman galois theory book and it says any field $F$.

Comment: @sziy Well, there you go, then. $\Bbb Z$ isn't a field, and therefore the monic requirement doesn't apply. But, as the answer below states, the gcd and lcm isn't always nicely defined.

Comment: And you've got the GCD and LCM mixed above: $2x-1\mid 4x^2-1$, so the GCD should be $2x-1$ and the LCM is $4x^2-1$. If $a\mid b$ in the ring, we can always define GCD and LCM, implicitly.

Comment: @Arthur Oh. I feel stupid now.

Answer (score 1):

The division algorithm doesn't work, in general, when the divisor is not monic in $\mathbb Z[x]$.

In particular, $\mathbb Z[x]$ is not a principal ideal domain, so the "natural" GCD of $2$ and $x$ is the ideal $\langle 2,x\rangle$, which is no a principal ideal, so it is not associated with an element of $\mathbb Z[x]$.

(The term "ideal" was chosen, in fact, because, ideally, there should be a common divisor of two or more element of a number field, and these numbers that "should exist" were considered "ideal divisors" even before they had a formal definition as subsets of the ring.)

You can still define the GCD in any ring with unique factorization, like $\mathbb Z[x]$, but it is a far weaker thing, because the best - or should I say "ideal" - definition of GCD is in terms of the sum of ideals.